# How to change CSS property to display:none when I press a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I'm trying to get two input boxes to show up in a table when I select 1 radio (present) and hide both of them if I select another (absent). I got this code to work but there was a small problem,

```js
function absentSwitch() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")[0].style.display = 'none';

}

function presentSwitch() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")[0].style.display = 'block';

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom2">
      <input type="radio" id="present" name="attendance" onclick="presentSwitch() " /</td>
      <td class="table-custom2 "><input type="radio" id="absent" name="attendance" onclick="absentSwitch() " /</td>
        <td class="table-custom3 "><input type="time " class="input-xsmall "></td>
        <td class="table-custom3 "><input type="time " class="input-xsmall "></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem in this code is, I can't use this for the next user below it. So I tried changing the `getElementsById` to `getElementsByClassName`, but only the first textbox was visible. Any way to fix it?

Also I read about a Jquery code thats much easier to perform, but couldnt find a tutorial to use it for my purpose. So any tips on that is appreciated.

Comment: I created a snippet from your code but it isn't working. Can you please edit it so we can reproduce your problem? Also please make sure you format your code correctly, you had a bunch of errors in your first HTML

Comment: jQuery: `$(".table-custom3").hide()` and `$(".table-custom3").show()`

Comment: @cloned edited it. I think its not showing it right because the css files are not here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty new to this, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but how exactly do I use that code?

Comment: That replaces `document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")[0].style.display = 'none';`

Comment: You're missing the `>` at the end of the radio inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to hide and show all the elements with a class.

Also, you need to use `inline-block` rather than `block` to prevent them from being put on different rows.

```js
function absentSwitch() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")).forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none');
}

function presentSwitch() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")).forEach(el => el.style.display = 'inline-block');

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom2">
      <input type="radio" id="present" name="attendance" onclick="presentSwitch() " /></td>
    <td class="table-custom2 "><input type="radio" id="absent" name="attendance" onclick="absentSwitch() " /></td>
    <td class="table-custom3 "><input type="time " class="input-xsmall "></td>
    <td class="table-custom3 "><input type="time " class="input-xsmall "></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, so this worked perfectly for the problem I mentioned, but it seems like I understood my problem incorrectly. (Guess I have a lot more to learn) When I used this and entered another user below, all the textboxes were shown/hidden but what I wanted was to individually do them for each user. (I'm supposed to get the user list via AJAX from a database in here but I have a lot to learn before getting there) Thanks a lot again

Comment: Sounds like you need to get the list of elements with the class just in the current row, not all of them. So you'll need to pass the row as an argument to functions, and then search for the elements just in that row.

Comment: I used a code before, to show/hide these for the single row, but i wasn't sure how to use it when getting data from the database because I wouldn't know the number of users. So adding them individually wasn't an option

Comment: There are lots of functions for traversing the DOM to find related elements. E.g. `row = element.closest("tr")` will find the row that contains `element`. And `row.querySelectorAll(".table-custom3")` will find the class members inside that row.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check those out now

Answer (score 1):

You need wrap your code inside `table` tag, if not `getElementsByClassName` not work. Also `getElementsByClassName` return array elements, you need get by index as

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")].map((item)=> {item.style.display = 'none'});
```

```js
function absentSwitch() {

    [...document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")].map((item)=> {item.style.display = 'none'});

}
function presentSwitch() {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom3")].map((item)=> {item.style.display = ''});

}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="table-custom2"><input type="radio" id="present" name="attendance" onclick="presentSwitch()" /></td>
<td class="table-custom2"><input type="radio" id="absent" name="attendance" onclick="absentSwitch()" /></td>
<td class="table-custom3"><input type="time" class="input-xsmall"></td>
<td class="table-custom3"><input type="time" class="input-xsmall"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: he added the table tag in an edit several minutes ago.

Comment: I tried this, but only the first textbox showed up. The other one was still hidden

Answer (score 1):

How about using classes that you toggle depending on the state of your sibling element ?

Something like

```css
.table-custom2.enabled ~ .table-custom3 { display: block; }
.table-custom2.disabled ~ .table-custom3  { display: none; }
```

```js
function absentSwitch() {
  document.querySelector(".table-custom2").classList.replace("enabled", "disabled");
}

function presentSwitch() {
  document.querySelector(".table-custom2").classList.replace("disabled", "enabled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your HTML code

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-custom2">
        <input type="radio" id="present" name="attendance" onclick="presentSwitch(this) "/></td>
        <td class="table-custom2 "><input type="radio" id="absent" name="attendance" onclick="absentSwitch(this) " /</td>
          <td class="table-custom3 "><input type="time " class="input-xsmall "></td>
          <td class="table-custom3 "><input type="time " class="input-xsmall "></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Here is javascript functions

```
function absentSwitch(event) {
     event.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].style.display = 'none';
     event.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].style.display = 'none';
}
function presentSwitch(event) {
     event.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].style.display = 'block';
     event.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].style.display = 'block';
}
```

**Now you can handle multiple inputs in table**